# Stack alignment in 64-bit systems

Tags: c, assembly, x86, memory-alignment, stack-memory

Can someone please explain why is SP (Stack Pointer) subtracted by 16 in this example on a 64-bit computer?

```
void function(int a, int b, int c) {
  char buffer1[5];
  char buffer2[10];
}

void main() {
  function(1,2,3);
}
```

Assembly:

```
_function:
LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    subl    $16, %esp  // --> This is what buffles me ...
    nop
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

I understand that it is subtracting 20 on a 32-bit system because the memory can be addressed in multiples of the word size (4 bytes). So then, 5-byte buffer is going to take 8 bytes of memory (2 words) and 10-byte buffer is going to take 12 bytes (3 words). When you sum it up, it is 20 bytes on the stack.

Furthermore, in a 64-bit system, word size is 8 bytes. By which logic, does it come to 16 bytes on the stack and how is it aligned then?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This code doesn't run in 64-bit mode.

Comment: There is no single thing that makes a computer a “32-bit system” or a “64-bit system.” Computers have several features that affect how much data it processes in various operations: width of the memory bus, width of processor registers, widths of data operands supported by instructions, width of the address space. A 16-byte stack alignment is not chosen entirely because any particular thing in the system mandates it but because the designers of the Application Binary Interface specified that the stack must be 16-byte aligned at function calls. This may be done for reasons of efficiency.

Comment: `function` is a leaf function; it doesn't call any others so there's no actual requirement on ESP within it at all.  The strange thing is that GCC's `main` doesn't seem to re-align the stack by 16; its `main` does 4 total pushes before a `call`: https://godbolt.org/z/h41WMM64o that should be misaligning the ESP to `ESP % 16 == 12` before the call, same as on function entry.

Comment: Oh, I see, it's doing inter-procedural analysis (even at `-O0`!) and seeing that the empty function doesn't need any stack alignment.  If we just give a prototype, not definition, we get the expected asm in `main`: https://godbolt.org/z/qWMeseW3h (including GCC's over-complicated alignment of `main`'s incoming stack pointer in 32-bit code; call it something else to avoid that; main is special.)

Comment: Does this answer the question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70894455/memory-allocation-and-unused-byte-in-basic-c-program/70894664#70894664

Comment: I think you missed the point of my question. Just imagine if `function` was not a leaf function. It still bothers me why those 2 char arrays take up 16 bytes of space on the stack?

Comment: @hrast See my link. Probably, the buffers do not need the alignment, but the stack itself does.

Comment: @hrast: Oh, I see.  10+5 = 15, and the compiler rounds that up to 16 because no matter what it's always going to keep the stack at least 4-byte aligned on 32-bit, not even temporarily misaligning it.  They aren't individually rounded up, and IDK where you're getting `20`.

Comment: If you want to look at asm for a non-leaf function, just do so by using a prototype for a function and calling it: https://godbolt.org/z/hME9GTTj9 . GCC then uses `sub $24, %esp`  (after one push) for a total of 28 bytes of stack movement to get back to 16-byte alignment.  If you pass the addresses of the buffers, you can see where it put them on the stack.

Comment: @PeterCordes
You can get 20 when word size is 4 bytes and arrays are individually aligned. So, the first array would be 12 instead of 10 bytes, the second array would be 8 instead of 5 bytes which is 20 together.
Then, you can also have a need for the stack to be aligned. Buffers are aligned to 20 bytes, and the stack can be aligned to 24 bytes. It depends on the system, I guess. 

P.S. I am reading this article ([link](http://phrack.org/issues/49/14.html#article)), and for example1.c I have `sub $16, %esp`, in the article it is `sub $20, %esp` and on my Linux VM it is `sub $24, %esp`.

Comment: Alignment is *always* to a power of 2; "aligned to 20 byte" is meaningless.  I assume you meant to say something about how far the stack pointer needs to move to create various size reservations with various alignments.  Anyway yes, if you wrote `alignas(4) char buffer1[5]`, and so on, that would stop GCC from packing them together into 16 bytes.  But you didn't do that, so GCC would only over-align the arrays if it could see code that was doing something with them where accessing multiple bytes at once was useful.  (Or if an individual array was 16 bytes or larger, as a heuristic.)